# matplotlib -> Could not load source '<__array_function__ internals>': Source unavailable

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estou tendo esse problema quando utilizo a função plt.show() ou plt.savefig('/path'):

[image: Erro]
O mesmo erro ocorre quando tento plotar um gráfico simples:

```js
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.stackplot(range(4), [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], labels=['a', 'b'])
plt.show()
```

E além de abrir uma nova aba no vscode, o plot.show() está mostrando o erro VauelError abaixo:

[image: erro2]
O erro provavelmente está no backend do matplot, pq o código está certo. Alguém sabe o que posso fazer?

Comment: Eu coloquei a caixa de script do java pq não to acostumado na formatação de perguntas aqui. O código é do python mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei buscando respostas e aparentemente esse é um erro do processo na geração do gráfico.

A correção foi simples: continuar rodando o código e atualizar com F5.

Resposta explicada: https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1291